# безуспешный рефакторинг c#

Tags: c#

Задание с ulearn.https://ulearn.me/course/basicprogramming/Praktika_Refaktoring__51aa14fb-1176-474f-a7ca-aafb86ff1967
Не понимаю, где ошибка, вот что выводит:

```
Неверный результат:
Как минимум один из тестов не пройден!
Название теста: DrawExpectedImage
Сообщение:
  Expected: less than 100.0d
  But was:  2556.0d
```

Стек вызовов:

```
   at RefactorMe.DrawingProgram_Tests.AssertImageEquals(Bitmap expected, Bitmap actual)
   at RefactorMe.DrawingProgram_Tests.DrawExpectedImage()
```

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using static System.Math;

namespace RefactorMe
{
    class Painter
    {
        public static double GetSqrt(double number)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(number);
        }

        public static double GetCos(double number)
        {
            return Math.Cos(number);
        }

        public static double GetSin(double number)
        {
            return Math.Sin(number);
        }

        static float x, y;
        static Graphics graphic;

        public static void Initialize(Graphics newGraphic)
        {
            graphic = newGraphic;
            graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            graphic.Clear(Color.Black);
        }

        public static void SetPosition(float x0, float y0)
        {
            x = x0;
            y = y0;
        }

        public double ShiftX(double length, double angle)
        {
            return x + length * GetCos(angle);
        }

        public double ShiftY(double length, double angle)
        {
            return y + length * GetSin(angle);
        }
        public void DrawPassedStep(Pen pen, double length, double angle)
        {
            var x1 = (float)ShiftX(length, angle);
            var y1 = (float)ShiftY(length, angle);
            graphic.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x1, y1);
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
        }
    }

    public class ImpossibleSquare
    {
        const float const1 = 0.375f;
        const float const2 = 0.04f;
        const double PI = Math.PI;
        Painter painter = new Painter();

        public static void Draw(int width, int height, double rotationAngle, Graphics graphic)
        {
            Painter.Initialize(graphic);
            var size = Math.Min(width, height);
            var color = Pens.Yellow;
            Painter painter = new Painter();

            void DrawSquareSide(double param)
            {
                painter.DrawPassedStep(color, size * const1, param);
                painter.DrawPassedStep(color, size * const2 * Painter.GetSqrt(2), param + PI / 4);
                painter.DrawPassedStep(color, size * const1, param + PI);
                painter.DrawPassedStep(color, size * const1 - size * const2, param + PI / 2);

                painter.ShiftX(size * const2, param - PI);
                painter.ShiftY(size * const2, param - PI);
                painter.ShiftX(size * const2 * Painter.GetSqrt(2), param + 3 * PI / 4);
                painter.ShiftY(size * const2 * Painter.GetSqrt(2), param + 3 * PI / 4);
            }

            var diagLength = Painter.GetSqrt(2) * (size * const1 + size * const2) / 2;
            var x0 = (float)(diagLength * Painter.GetCos(PI / 4 + PI) + width / 2f);
            var y0 = (float)(diagLength * Painter.GetSin(PI / 4 + PI) + height / 2f);

            Painter.SetPosition(x0, y0);

            DrawSquareSide(0);
            DrawSquareSide(-PI / 2);
            DrawSquareSide(PI);
            DrawSquareSide(PI / 2);

        }
    }
}
```

Причем предыдущий код работал исправно:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace RefactorMe
{
    class Painter
    {
        const double PI = Math.PI;
        public static double GetSqrt(double number)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(number);
        }

        public static double GetCos(double number)
        {
            return Math.Cos(number);
        }

        public static double GetSin(double number)
        {
            return Math.Sin(number);
        }

        static float x, y;
        static Graphics graphic;

        public static void Initialize(Graphics newGraphic)
        {
            graphic = newGraphic;
            graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            graphic.Clear(Color.Black);
        }

        public static void Set_position(float x0, float y0)
        { 
            x = x0;
            y = y0;
        }

        public static void MakeIt(Pen pen, double length, double angle)
        {
            //Делает шаг длиной dlina в направлении ugol и рисует пройденную траекторию
            var x1 = (float)(x + length * GetCos(angle));
            var y1 = (float)(y + length * GetSin(angle));
            graphic.DrawLine(pen, x, y, x1, y1);
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
        }

        public static void Change(double length, double angle)
        {
            x = (float)(x + length * GetCos(angle));
            y = (float)(y + length * GetSin(angle));
        }
    }

    public class ImpossibleSquare
    {
        const double PI = Math.PI;
        public static double GetSqrt(double number)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(number);
        }

        public static double GetCos(double number)
        {
            return Math.Cos(number);
        }

        public static double GetSin(double number)
        {
            return Math.Sin(number);
        }

        public static void Draw(int width, int height, double angleOfRotation, Graphics graphic)
        {
            // ugolPovorota пока не используется, но будет использоваться в будущем
            Painter.Initialize(graphic);

            var size = Math.Min(width, height);
            
            void drawIt(double param1)
            {
                Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, param1);
                Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.04f * GetSqrt(2), param1 + PI / 4);
                Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f, param1 + PI);
                Painter.MakeIt(Pens.Yellow, size * 0.375f - size * 0.04f, param1 + PI / 2);

                Painter.Change(size * 0.04f, param1 - PI);
                Painter.Change(size * 0.04f * GetSqrt(2), param1 + 3 * PI / 4);
            }
            
            var diagonal_length = GetSqrt(2) * (size * 0.375f + size * 0.04f) / 2;
            var x0 = (float)(diagonal_length * GetCos(PI / 4 + PI)) + width / 2f;
            var y0 = (float)(diagonal_length * GetSin(PI / 4 + PI)) + height / 2f;

            Painter.Set_position(x0, y0);

            //Рисуем 1-ую сторону
            drawIt(0);

            //Рисуем 2-ую сторону
            drawIt(-PI / 2);

            //Рисуем 3-ю сторону
            drawIt(PI);

            //Рисуем 4-ую сторону
            drawIt(PI / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Так в чем же все-таки ошибка? спасите помогите

Comment: Начните заново, после каждого изменения, проверяйте, что ничего не сломали

Comment: Вначале, попробуйте покрыть автоматизированными тестами! Юнит тесты спасли не одни ноги при рефакторинге

Comment: @PeterLavreniuk да, но нет. Тест как раз уже имеется, это указано в вопросе.

Comment: @aepot тест на уровне комита решения. а не на уровне солюшена, когда каждую правку можно прогнать по тестами. вместо того чтобы отправлять на сайт...